# How does C++ list<T> act on inserting elements?

Tags: c++, list, insert, indexing

I have a question regarding C++ lists. Below is the code I don't quite understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Customer {
string firstName;
string lastName;
};

void replace(list<Customer>& customers, int index, Customer item)
{
std::list<Customer>::iterator it = customers.begin();
advance(it, index);
*it = item;
}

Customer get (list<Customer>& customers, int index)
{
std::list<Customer>::iterator it = customers.begin();
advance(it, index);
return *it;
}

int main() {

list<Customer> customers;
Customer c1;
c1.firstName = "Jack";
c1.lastName = "Smith";
Customer c2;
c2.firstName = "Jane";
c2.lastName = "Doe";

insert(customers, 50, c1);

cout << get(customers,0).firstName << endl; //outputs Jack even though I inserted it at index 50

insert(customers, 49, c2);

cout << get(customers,0).firstName << endl; //outputs Jane

cout << get(customers,50).firstName << endl; //where did Jack go?

return 0;
}
```

I'm using Eclipse C++ and gcc. So my questions are:

1 - why doesn't this example crash as I'm inserting items straight off at index 50?

2 - what happens to spots at indexes 0 - 49?

3 - in the insert() and get() methods is it correct to check the index with the size of the list and make sure they don't pass the list boundaries?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, at the point where you advance the iterator beyond `end()`. That means the program can do anything at all - including not crashing and doing what you see.

Comment: Also your insert doesn't insert but replace the item at the given position.

Comment: Changed the method name from insert() to replace() , missed that one. So the proper thing to do would be to manually check if the index passed in is in the expected bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why doesn't this example crash as I'm inserting items straight off at index 50?

Because undefined behaviour doesn't necessarily cause a crash.

You are not inserting at index 50. You're taking a past-the-end iterator (which can't be incremented), then attempting to increment it 50 times; then leaping further into undefined behaviour by dereferencing the thoroughly invalid iterator you end up with.

The GNU library implements `list` as a circular list, with a dummy node to act as the "past the end" position. So, in this implementation, incrementing an off-the-end iterator will return to the start of the list, and dereferencing it will lead to accessible memory, so there won't be a crash. You simply write to that dummy element, then overwrite it.

Other implementations may behave differently when you perform invalid operations.

> what happens to spots at indexes 0 - 49?

They don't exist, since you never put anything in the list.

> in the insert() and get() methods is it correct to check the index with the size of the list and make sure they don't pass the list boundaries?

Yes. `advance` won't check for the end of the sequence, since it has no way of knowing what that is. You'll get undefined behaviour if you try to advance beyond the end, so it's up to you to check first.

Answer (score 0):

Your list has 0 elements. Try to call `customers.size()`.

So `std::advance` returns `customers.end()`, which is invalid iterator. By dereferencing it you'l get exception or **UB**, depending on your build options.